# How to create method like Html.TextBox that adds attributes to textbox rendered?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm familiar with using the `Html.TextBox` method to render a textbox.  Suppose that I want to write a method that is similar to `Html.TextBox`, but takes a single additional string attribute called `Abc` which renders a TextBox just like one rendered by TextBox, but adds an attribute called `data-abc` with the value specified by `Abc`.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with that seems to work:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBox<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string value, object htmlAttributes, string Abc)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> myHtmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        myHtmlAttributes.Add("data-abc", Abc);

        return helper.TextBox(propertyName, value, myHtmlAttributes);
    }
```

Comment: While correct, it depends on if you want to do this routinely or with different attribute names.  The framework allows for data attributes to be added by default, so I'd be tempted to just use those.

Answer (score 2):

Add the attribute data_abc to the optional parameters and it will add it as data-abc.

```
@Html.TextBox("Name", "Default Value", new { data_abc = "data" });
```

Good luck!